# C# Чем отличается механизм наследования простых функций от виртуальных

Tags: c#

Поднялся интересный вопрос. Я как послушный мальчик прочел в доках(микрософт док), что определение виртуал требуется если я планирую разрешать перекрытие методов в потомках, а если я такого определения перед методом не напишу, то фиг он в потомке перекроется.

Эксперимента ради написал следующий код.

```
class A
{
    void  FuncA()
    {
    }
}

class B : A
{
    new void FuncA()
    {
         base.FuncA();
    }
}
```

Получается, что если верить микрософт доку такая конструкция не должна компилироваться. А если скомпилируется вызов базовой функции в таком потомке не должен пройти.

Запуск проходит, обращение к предку проходит.

Обьясните или дайте ссылку на чтонибудь почитать. 
Какой механизм наследования и в чемже разница между обычной функцией и виртуальной?

Comment: Ссылку на доки. И да, если вы приедете тип к А, то окажется, что метод не перекрыт, вызовется именно метод из А, при override вызовется перегруженный метод

Comment: Прочитайте ещё про разницу между перегрузкой и переопределением, и всё станет на места.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перекрытие в данном случае не произойдёт при приведении одного типа в другой:

```
var b = new B();
b.FuncA(); // будет тот что определён в B класса
var a = (А) b;
a.FuncA(); // всё равно будет вызов метода из B класса
```

Уже есть [хороший ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/749191/274132) по схожей теме.

Comment: Дошло. Кривым путем но дошло :(